# How to do Axios request from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've tried the following in Firebase Cloud Function to do an Axios request but it didn't work.

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
    
    exports.checkIP = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        cors(req, res, () => {
            if( req.method !== "GET" ) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: "Not allowed"
                });
            }
    
            return axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: data.ip
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                })
            })
    
        })
    })
```

I've also googled a lot for seeing some example of how to use Axios with Cloud Functions but found none. The above code is not returning anything.

Can anyone help?

**P.S.:** I've already added billing details in my Firebase account and not using the free Spark plan, rather using Blaze plan.

#### Edit:

I've finally able to do this using the `request-promise` node package but still no idea about how to do it with `axios`. As no matter what I try, `axios` doesn't work in Firebase cloud functions. This is what I did:

`npm i --save cors request request-promise`

Then this is the code I run: https://gist.github.com/isaumya/0081a9318e4f7723e0123f4def744a0e

Maybe it will help someone. If anyone knows how to do it with `Axios` please answer below.

Comment: Are you on a paid plan (Flame or Blaze)? If not you cannot call an external service from a Cloud Function. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ "The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services."

Comment: Yes, I am thee paid plan adding the billing details. So that's not the case.

Comment: try returning a promise from your request handler, e.g. `return axios.get ...`

Comment: Hi @JamesPoag, tried but didn't work.

Comment: @JamesPoag check the updated code above. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I changed `data.ip` to `response.data.ip` and added `return` before the two `res.status(...` lines and the deployed cloud function works for me using Axios when I try it.

The code I have is

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

    exports.checkIP = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req, res, () => {
        if (req.method !== "GET") {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Not allowed"
          });
        }
    
        return axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            return res.status(200).json({
              message: response.data.ip
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            })
          })
    
      })
    });
```

When I invoke the function I get back a reply like
{
"message": "127.168.121.130"
}

Comment: For everyone try to plainly run an example from command line locally: U MUST wrap your function in a `functions.https.onRequest()`.. otherwise it will fail to execute.. took me 30 minutes to figure out how stupid I was think I could just run stuff :D

Comment: what is cors for? can I do without?

Comment: I tried the example without `cors` and it still worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. An HTTP request with `axios` returns the following error message :
`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

[Here is an explanation of what is going on and how to get around this](https://makandracards.com/makandra/28847-dealing-with-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-on-javascript)

You can use the following package : 
https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe

I'm not sure about the consistency of this approach and personally went for `request-promise`, which is heavier than axios but allows straightforward HTTP requests.